# Encrypting connections strings in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, encryption, advanced-installer

Hi I'm hoping this isn't too vague to get some help with!

We've searched for several days now and cannot get an answer that works. We use Advanced Installer for different projects and need a sensible way to encrypt the connection strings for sites that do NOT use windows authentication into the sql server.

We've tried encryption after installation, running custom DLL's in Advanced Installer and all sorts. Nothing works because of Microsoft's frustrating permissions fortress around Program Files folder.

Does anyone know of a decent way to do this that does not involve Windows Authentication on the database?

Any help would be very warmly appreciated. As you can imagine, this request is made as a last ditch attempt to find a good solution.

I'm rather shocked that there isn't one that is fairly standard - but if you don't use Windows Authentication on SQL server, I don't see one as far as I can tell.

Thank you in advance for any help offered!

Warmest regards
Richard

**Edit:** From what I understand the encrypt/decrypt can only be done on the same machine - preventing me from shipping an encrypted app.config. The key is based on a machine.config that differs by machine.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration

Comment: The reason that there isn't a standard method is because since you will also need to _**decrypt**_ the information, there will always be some code/data available somewhere that you can use to decrypt it. There simply is no way to keep it 100% secure on a user's machine. What I mentioned above is probably one of the most recommended solutions though.

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for coming back to me. Our problem appears to be being unable to get anything to write to Program Files to allow us to encrypt on a user's machine. The only solution we haven't tried is ditching Microsoft's plan entirely and installing our program to a non program files location thus allowing use to modify the application's config file and encrypt the string for that machine. It seems bonkers that we have to get around the Program Files protection to encrypt after installation but I've not found a better way so far.

Comment: This is what drove us both nuts yesterday - we can actually encrypt/decrypt the strings but of course we must perform the original encryption on the machine in question. Fair enough but Microsoft don't give any standard way to do it at all. So we can't get Advanced Installer to run anything after the fact - it's an odd catch-22 situation.

Doesn't help that these are desktop only, winforms apps albeit using the current .Net framework.

Comment: But the link I gave suggests a solution that is somewhat standard - storing it in app.config as an encrypted value (the encryption and decryption is taken care of by the Framework) - did you try it? It only needs to be encrypted once, then you just ship it with your application.

Comment: As for your other issue: You can write to Program Files if you have administrator privileges. I don't know how Advanced Installer works, but if you can force it (and your custom actions) to be run with administrator privileges you'll be able to write to the Program Files directory. -- I use the built-in Setup Project in VS 2010, and it always asks for admin privileges when installing (if you choose 'No' it will simply cancel the installation).

Comment: Here's a thread I found on Advanced Installer's forum. It should explain how you can run your custom actions (DLLs) with administrator privileges: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10840 -- Also see this in from their User Guide: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-action-properties.html

Comment: Hi Vincent, my colleague and I will work through everything you've given us, thank you.

Comment: Not had chance since our earlier commentary to continue the investigation - it'll be Monday now. However, I'd like to feed back and assuming we succeed, mark your help as the answer then as well.

Comment: Looks like we are going round in circles on all these so far. The encryption/decryption will not work the moment we have to deploy to other machines. My colleague has been on this about a week nearly and nothing work - Advanced Installer refuses to run DLL's after install, so we're shafted there. It's a peculiar problem because many clients will be unable to use Windows authentication to Azure SQL. They are not on Azure AD either. Thanks for offering your advice Visual Vincent - it seems MS has us shafted on this sadly.

Comment: Is direct access to the database necessary? If not then you could set up a web service via WCF (or just a regular website running PHP) that you send/get data to/from. The web service/website is then responsible for updating/querying the database.

Comment: For some projects I believe your suggestions (WCF etc) would be the correct answer tbh. It's the old winforms projects that are a bit of a nuisance. As my colleague is working through Advanced installer and got a bit closer, when it's solved I'll add the answer here. But, I think REST API / WCF or some variations would be far better for future projects for sure.

Comment: FWIW you can just use a website with PHP support and program it to get/update data in the database for you based on the requests it gets. Then you just use a [**`WebRequest`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to send data to the website from your application. It shouldn't be too hard to implement even in older apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the key to solving this with Advanced Installer - it can't run DLLs that are built in managed code, so you need to use another toolset called Wix to create a DLL that Advanced Installer can use. The instructions for that can be found here: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html

For the encryption we're after, this is the function I created as a custom action in the Wix project (for clarity, minus the try-catch, file check and logging that our actual code has):

```
<CustomAction()>
Public Shared Function Encrypt(session As Session) As ActionResult
    Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(session.CustomActionData("ExecutablePath"))
    Dim section As ConnectionStringsSection = TryCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
    If section.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then Return ActionResult.SkipRemainingActions
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
    If Not section.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then Return ActionResult.Failure
    config.Save()
    Return ActionResult.Success
End Function
```

When you build the project, it generates two DLL files: a normal .dll and a .CA.dll. In the Advanced Installer project, add the .CA.dll to the included files (preferably as a temporary file since it's only needed during installation). Then go to custom actions, add a new "Call Function From Attached Native DLL" action, point it at the same .CA.dll file as you selected to add to the project, and then set up the rest of the action like this:
[(attached image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aefmv.png)

...where [#ConfigEncryptionTestProgram.exe] should be replaced with your executable!

The important bits here are the position of the action in the sequence (just before Finish Execution), the execution time (commit), and the execution option that makes it run with privileges so that it can get around Microsoft's restriction on modifying files in the Program Files folder.

Comment: This has been a working answer where we can't use Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and have written not a single line of real code.

I have just added to the installer a custom action for encryption:

- Launch File (With Sequence)
- File to launch: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe
- Command line: -pe connectionStrings -app /myappname
- Hide program's window
- You would set "Run as administrator" (not applicable to us, because our installer completely runs as administrator)
- Execution Time: Immediately
- Wait for custom action to finish before proceeding
- DO NOT Fail installation if custom action returns an error

and another one for decryption, same settings, but with command line `-pd` instead of `-pe`.

And then I have moved the decryption before the "Dialogs->Searches" stage, and the encryption behind the "Execution->InstallFinalize" stage:

[image]